# CNC router bit to cut french cleat?

Tags: router, router-bit, cnc

I'm looking for the name or even a specific bit recommendation that could cut a french cleat angle (45 angle) into a piece of wood. Much like a dovetail bit but at a 45 degree. Do these bits even exist? See photo below:

[image]

Something that looks like this but instead of 2 separate pieces laminated together, I would like to machine it into a single piece.

Comment: You're trying to use a sledgehammer to crack an egg here. I would strongly recommend you not pursue this, build up instead. Quite apart from the possibility that this isn't actually possible to do neatly and cleanly it's not a lot slower (honest!) but it's a whole lot cheaper, and for something utilitarian like this why go an expensive route?

Comment: @Graphus The part is being cut by a CNC.

Comment: I'm betting clearance angles mean you won't be able to but let's say you can find the bit you're hoping for, what if the machining turns out to be difficult or slow? There's nothing forcing you to make the bracket(s) as a single piece other than an arbitrary decision made in advance. Is it worth pursuing when a *much* easier path is available *right now*? The light-coloured part is as easy to shape as could be, the darker portion equally so. Make 'em separately, tack 'em together, done. What's the problem? You could be done already!

Answer (score 1):

You want a 45 degree inverted chamfer bit.

Many of these will have a bearing on the bottom - this will be removable, but there might still be a nub that keeps it from cutting flush.  Maybe you could grind it off?

[image: inverted chamfer bit]

Comment: Grinding a router bit that is going to be run at 18,000 RPM doesn't sound like something _I_ would want to do, but you might have a different safety threshold than I do...

Comment: I'm thinking there may be a small ridge on the bottom center to stand the bearing off a bit.  It's probably just a washer, but I haven't found a picture of the bottom of one without the bearing on it to see.  In any case, carefully grinding or filing a thin ridge in the center of the bottom wouldn't concern me to much.

Comment: from my understanding, he needs two pass with two different tools:  one with the 45 chamfer bit and then finish up with a straight bit to get the french cleat shape. I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Found these bits on Amazon

https://www.amazon.ca/Degree-Straight-Shank-Dovetail-Cutter/dp/B01JUDP12E/ref=sr_1_7?keywords=dovetail+bit+45+degree&qid=1556519761&s=gateway&sr=8-7

Little bit odd with all the flutes but I think it'll do just fine at least in the short run.

[image]

Comment: Please let us know how much scorching you get on the vertical portion of the milled recess.